# IntelliJ enables annotation processing every time the gradle project is refreshed

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

I am building and running my project using IntelliJ IDEA and not Gradle.

In Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors, I have two profiles: Default and Gradle Imported. I disabled annotation processing for both profiles. Whenever I build and run my project, it works as expected and the annotation processor does not run. However, any time the Gradle project refreshes, i.e. a dependency changed, IntelliJ re-enables annotation processing for the 'Gradle Imported' profile, so I have to manually disable it again.

Is there any way to persist the setting through Gradle refreshes? I want the annotation processor to run when doing a Gradle build but not when building locally using IntelliJ. I noticed .idea/compiler.xml gets regenerated every time I refresh the Gradle project, which seems to be what changes enabled from false to true. Is there a way to force 'enabled' to be false in this file? Thanks.

I tried to add this to my build script with 'enabled' set to false, https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-enable-compiler-annotation-process, but it didn't seem to work since this changes the IntelliJ project file and not compiler.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround. Posting it here in case anyone else wonders across this. I updated by build.gradle file to have the following, which deletes all annotation processing settings from compiler.xml whenever a Gradle sync is done.

```
task disableAnnotationProcessorInIntelliJ {

        def isIntelliJ = System.getProperty('idea.active') == 'true'
        if(isIntelliJ) {
            File compilerXmlFile = new File("./.idea/compiler.xml")
            Node compilerXml = new groovy.xml.XmlParser().parse(compilerXmlFile)
            Node compilerConfiguration = compilerXml.component.find { it.@name == "CompilerConfiguration" } as Node
            NodeList annotationProcessing = compilerConfiguration.annotationProcessing
            for (int i = 0; i < annotationProcessing.size(); i++) {
                compilerConfiguration.remove(annotationProcessing.get(i) as Node)
            }

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            groovy.xml.XmlNodePrinter nodePrinter = new groovy.xml.XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter))
            nodePrinter.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
            nodePrinter.print(compilerXml)
            compilerXmlFile.text = stringWriter.toString()
        }
}

idea {
    project {
        settings {
            taskTriggers {
                afterSync tasks.getByName("disableAnnotationProcessorInIntelliJ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be [expected behavior](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html#annotation_processing).

There is a [YouTrack Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-319720/Gradle-Annotation-Processors-imported-via-build.gradle-are-enabled-on-every-Sync) on this topic and you can upvote it to change that.